# Splitting multiple input files into multiple outputs using split function in linux

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop, split, vcf-variant-call-format

I have 8 files I would like to split into 5 chunks per file. I would normally do this individually but would like to run this as a loop. I work within a HPC.

I have created a list of the file names and labelled it "variantlist.txt". My code is:

```
for f in 'cat variantlist.txt'; do split ${f} -n 5 -d; done
```

However, it only splits the final file in the variantlist.txt file outputting 5 chunks from the final entry only.

Even if I list the files individually:

```
for f in chr001.vcf chr002 ...chr008.vcf ; do split ${f} -n 5 -d; done
```

It still only splits the final file into 5 chunks.

Not sure where I am going wrong here. The desired output would be 40 chunks, 5 per chromosome. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: Don't use `for f in 'cat variantlist.txt';`. For the same result, try `lst=( $(<variantlist.txt) ); for f in "${lst[@]}"` or `while read f;do ... done<variantlist.txt` or even `xargs ... < variantlist.txt`.

Comment: @PaulHodges thanks! Is the cat method not as efficient?

Comment: See [the Useless Use of `cat` awards](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#cat) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The split is creating the same set of files each time and overwriting the previous ones. Here's one way to handle that -

```
for f in $(<variantlist.txt)  # don't use cat
do  mkdir -p $f.split         # make a subdir for the files
    ( cd $f.split &&          # change into the subdir only in a subshell
      split ../$f -n 5 -d     # split from there
    )                         # close the subshell, parent still in base dir
done
```

Or you could just do this -

```
while read f             # grab each filename
do split $f -n 5 -d      # split it
   for x in x??          # for each split file
   do mv $x $f.$x        # rename it to include the parent file name
   done
done < variantlist.txt   # take names from this file
```

This is a lot slower, but doesn't use subdirs.

My favorite, though -

```
xargs -I {} split {} -n 5 -d {} < variantlist.txt
```

The last arg becomes the PREFIX for `split` instead of the default of `x`.

**EDIT** -- with 2 billion lines per file, use this one:

```
for f in $(<variantlist.txt)
do split "$f" -d -n 5 "$f" & # run all in background at the same time
done
```

Comment: Do you have enough space? Need compression?

Comment: I'm running it interactively on the HPC so will update you once it's done. No errors yet and it's running for longer than previously which is a good sign (using your edited method).

Comment: still running! Not sure how long one would expect it to take

Comment: two billion lines will take a while.... did you try it on smaller datasets first?

Comment: yup worked on a smaller dataset. Many thanks again for your help!

Comment: Did it finish on the full data? How long did it take?

Comment: timed out after a day (ran it as a 24 hour job) having got half way through - so split 4 files into 5 chunks with 4 files remaining. Will run it as a longer job!

Answer (score 1):

When using `split` the `-n` swicth will determine the number of output files that the orinal is split into...

You need `-l` for the number of lines you need, 5 in your case:

```
 split -l 5 ${f}
```

Comment: thanks for the response. The file actually has 2 billion lines and I want 5 files out of this so roughly 400 million lines per file. If I write: split -l 400000000 ${f} in the loop would that be better?

Comment: Yes the numbers there passed to `-l` will give you tat many lines per file.